British TV-movie, 1980s, Indian/Pakistani girl and white boy teen-couple, dinner, flashing
I'm looking for a British TV(?)-movie I saw on Norwegian TV while I went to junior-high - so that'd be between 1987 and 1990... it may have been a few years older (guess five tops).
It's about the relationship between two teens (guess 16-18 or older) - a typical British white (working-class?) boy, and a Indian/Pakistani girl (well, 2nd generation British-Indian/Pakistani) - and the cultural difficulty they face.
The only scene I really remember, is when the boy is invited to a family-dinner by the girls parents.  It's the boy, the girl, the girl's mother and father, and the girl's uncle or cousin.  The girl excuses herself early and leaves the table, and the parents starts questioning the boy.
The parents sits with their back to the door - and perhaps a window/opening into the hallway; and the boy sits facing them.  The uncle sits besides the boy.  While the boy talks to the parents, the girl goes through the hall.  She stops - maybe makes some faces to show her parents are boring through (I think) the window... then she pulls-up her sweater and flashes her breasts at him!  Of course, just then her uncle looks up from his food, and almost chokes.
As I said, this is the only scene I remember.  In my defense, I was a 14 year old teenage boy at the time - and it really was a pair of outstanding... young actors. ;-)
So, can anybody remember something like this?  Know it's very vague...

Bend it Like Beckham sort of fits.  The ethnicity is right and the Indian girl is changing her shirt in the white boys room

Reminds me a little of this older question, couldn't be the same show, could it?

Nope, it's not them...  What I'm looking for is older and not a series.  Thanks for the tips though, sounds like interesting series and movie.

The scene you describe is in My Beautiful Laundrette but the guy is Pakistani too. There is a white guy in the film - his boyfriend. Poor girl flashed him for nothing...

Could this be My Beautiful Launderette (1985)?
The scene with Rita Wolf flashing her boyfriend is quite memorable, and results in his uncle choking.

